# Server Render Using NuxtJs

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

Hello Iam trying to make a server render to my application . Iam having an Api that get me the data In the code the server render is working But I want after rendering the server It return to the client side .

What is happening now is the iam getting the data but I cannot see them untile I stop the server and change it to false

Or in Other mean Something rather than the pending why because when the `server : false` is running the api is not been show on the network of browser and that what I want

```
<template>
<Head v-if="!pending">
<Title>AMIT Learning</Title>
<Meta
  name="description"
  :content="'AMIT Learning is Professional Training and Coaching in Engineering, 
   Embedded Systems, machine learning, Ai, flutter, cybersecurity, web development.'"
/>
<Meta property="og:url" :content="'https://dev.amit-learning.com/eg/'" />
<Meta property="og:type" content="website" />
<Meta
  property="og:title"
  :content="`AMIT Learning | Best programming courses`"
/>
<Meta
  property="og:description"
  :content="`AMIT Learning is Professional Training and Coaching in Engineering, 
  Embedded Systems, machine learning, Ai, flutter, cybersecurity, web development.`"
/>
<Meta
  property="og:keyword"
   :content="'diplomas, programming, Diploma, embedded systems course, learning, 
   courses, web Development, full stack, web developer, ai, machine Learning, software 
   testing, flutter, mobile application, programming courses, cyber security, education 
center, amit learning, technology, software engineering course'"
 />
 </Head>
  <Spinner v-if="pending"/>
    <div v-else>
  <VideoCard />
   <Rating />
  
    <!-- Our Diplomas  -->
   <ex_diplomas :diplomasData="diplomas.data" />

  <!-- Most Viral Groups  -->
  <div class="viral">
    <viral :diplomasData="diplomas.data" />
   </div>
   <div class="viral_res">
     <viral_res :diplomasData="diplomas.data" />
   </div>
  <StudentFeedbcak />

  <!-- Certifications Section -->
  <Certifications />
</div>
</template>
```

```
<script setup>
import Rating from "../components/HomeComponents/Rating.vue";
import ex_diplomas from "../components/HomeComponents/Explore_Diplomas.vue";
import viral from "../components/HomeComponents/Viral_Groups.vue";
import viral_res from "../components/HomeComponents/Viral_GroupsRes.vue";
import StudentFeedbcak from "../components/HomeComponents/StudentFeedbcak.vue";
import VideoCard from "../components/HomeComponents/video-card.vue";
import Certifications from "../components/HomeComponents/Certifications.vue";
import Spinner from "../components/Spinner.vue";
import config from "~/config.js";
useSeoMeta({
      charset: "utf-8",
      Title: "AMIT Learning | Best programming courses",
      description:
        "AMIT Learning is Professional Training and Coaching in Engineering, Embedded Systems, machine learning, Ai, flutter, cybersecurity, web development.",
      title: "AMIT Learning",
      keywords:
        "diplomas, programming, Diploma, embedded systems course, learning, courses, web Development, full stack, web developer, ai, machine Learning, software testing, flutter, mobile application, programming courses, cyber security, education center, amit learning, technology, software engineering course",
    });
      const { pending, data: diplomas } = await useFetch(
        `${config.VITE_CRM_IP}website-service/list-diplomas-home-page`,
        {
          lazy: true,
          server:false,// I want to stop this after render and activate the client render
        }
      );
</script>
```